Understanding and proving $\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac1n\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{\sin (k^2\frac{\pi}{2n})}{\sin (k\frac{\pi}{2n})}=\frac12$
This is an interesting formula about trigonometric functions
I accidentally found this wonderful formula on wolfram, can anyone prove it? Maybe it can be promoted as this
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac1n\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{\sin (k^2\frac{\pi}{2n})}{\sin (k\frac{\pi}{2n})}=\frac12$$

Welcome to MSE. It is in your best interest that you type your posts (using MathJax) instead of posting links to pictures.

Hi, welcome to Math SE. Since the number of degrees in a right-angle is an arbitrary convention equivalent to saying how big a degree is, you're basically asking why $\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac1n\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{\sin\frac{\pi k^2}{2n}}{\sin\frac{\pi k}{2n}}=\frac12$. If you want to edit that conjecture into your question, the MathJax is \lim_{n\to\infty}\frac1n\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{\sin\frac{\pi k^2}{2n}}{\sin\frac{\pi k}{2n}}=\frac12.

Thank you for your answer, this is my first time asking, I'm really sorry

What I have a question about is why the upper limit of the sum becomes infinite.

Thank you, I have understood the problem and your answer really helped me a lot

https://www.zhihu.com/question/664168715/answer/3593538331 form  Chinese  Zhihu.

Too big for a comment:
Setting $h=\frac1n$ we can write the sum as
$$
\frac1n \sum_{k=1}^{n} \frac{\sin (k^2\frac{\pi}{2n})}{\sin (k\frac{\pi}{2n})}
= \sum_{k=1}^{n} \frac{\sin (n\frac{\pi}{2}(\frac k n)^2)}{\sin(\frac{\pi}{2}\frac k n)} h.
$$
When $n$ is large this sum can be seen as an approximation for the integrals
$$
I_n := \int_0^1 \frac{\sin(n\frac{\pi}{2}x^2)}{\sin(\frac{\pi}{2}x)}\,dx
$$
so we need to study how this sequence behaves in the limit $n\to\infty.$

I calculated this integral on wolfram and got no value.can you give me some tips？

@user1373518. I don't know how to evaluate it, not even in the limit. I just checked that I got a value around 0.5 using numerical integration in Graph.

You can try setting n to even and odd numbers respectively, and you will find more wonderful conclusions.

I personally feel that this has something to do with the plural number

$$I=\int_0^1\frac{\sin\frac{\pi n x^2}2}{\sin\frac{\pi x}2}dx=\frac1{\sqrt{2\pi n}}\Im\int_0^\frac{\pi n}2\frac{e^{ix}}{\sqrt x\sin\sqrt\frac{\pi x}{2n}}dx$$
Integrating in the complex plane along a quarter-circle (with small arch)
$$I=\Im\frac i{\sqrt{2\pi n}}\int_0^{\pi/2}\frac{d\phi}{\sqrt\frac\pi{2n}}+\Im\frac1{\sqrt{2\pi n}}\int_0^\frac{\pi n}2\frac{e^{-t}e^{\pi i/4}}{\sqrt t\sin\big(\sqrt\frac{\pi t}{2n}e^{\pi i/4}\big)}dt+\Im\int_1^{e^{\frac{\pi i}4}}\frac {e^{\frac{\pi nz^2}2}}{\sin\frac{\pi z}2}dz$$
$$=\frac12+\frac1{12n}-\frac{\cos\frac{\pi n}2}{\pi n}+O\Big(\frac1{n^2}\Big)$$
